# iphone - more than one button in leftBarButtonItem of a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I push a new view controller onto the navigation stack, the leftbarbuttonitem changes into the Title of the previous view controller, as expected. But I need to add an additional button to the nav bar, just to the right of the back button. I still want the back button to work as normal. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom view on the navigationbar. Then, implement 2 buttons and add them on the custom view, one for back button, and one for additional button you want.

The navigationBar can be obtained by the property of [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController).

Edit: 
[UINavigationBar class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationBar), it is a sub-class of UIView.

Comment: How can you set/add a custom view on navigation bar. There is no API that I can see to do that. Or you mean to add a subview inside navigationBar?

Comment: navigationBar is a sub-class of UIView, so you can add a subview inside navigationBar.

Comment: I have basically done this, but the problem is that you can't programatically create a "Back" button. You can choose either backBarButtonItem or leftBarButtonItem. If you choose leftBarButtonItem you can't place the back button inside it.

Comment: Yes. it is because you use UIBarButtonItem for button on UINavigationBar. And what I said is to use 2 UIButtons and UIView which are put above UINavigationBar.